# Matrix operation between 2D and 3D (or 4D) matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to know if there is a specific linear algebra way to represent the following operation.
There is matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
There is a 3D matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m \times l}$ where $l = n*m$.
I want to multiply $x_{i,j} \in X$ to all $n\times m$ elements in one 'layer' of $A$ and then sum all the $a_{i,j,\cdotp}$ of the different layers of $A$. This should result in a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
For example:
$X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 \\
3 & 5 
\end{bmatrix}  $,
$A[\cdotp,\cdotp,1] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $,
$A[\cdotp,\cdotp,2] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $,
$A[\cdotp,\cdotp,3] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $,
$A[\cdotp,\cdotp,4] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} $

$2*A[\cdotp,\cdotp,1] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $
$4*A[\cdotp,\cdotp,2] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $
$3*A[\cdotp,\cdotp,3] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $
$5*A[\cdotp,\cdotp,4] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 5 
\end{bmatrix} $
And then, sum the layers element wise:
$B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 5 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 7 \\
0 & 5 
\end{bmatrix}$

I'm thinking that $A$ could be defined as a 4-dimmensional matrix $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m \times n \times m}$ so that $x_{i,j}$ should be multiply to all the elements of $A_{\cdotp,\cdotp, i,j}$  .

Comment: If this is a programming question I recommend python. If it is a pure math question I recommend the so called index notation. You can find lots of examples under this name in MSE. It is just a conventient way of writing down what you multiply with what and what you are summing up.